# devise force sign-in user goes logout automaitcaly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to do some guest user functionality. After creating user I am doing sign in forcefully. user logged in successfuly and current_user is available in the same method. But after that when I redirect to other controller I lost current_user.

```
 class Notloggedin::AccountRequestsController < Notloggedin::BaseController
  def create
    params[:account_request][:user_attributes][:email] = params[:account_request][:contact_email]
    params[:account_request][:user_attributes][:first_name] = params[:account_request][:contact_name]
    params[:account_request][:user_attributes][:guest] = true
    user = User.where(email: params[:account_request][:contact_email], guest: false)
    @account_request = AccountRequest.new(permitted_account_request_params)
    if user.empty? && @account_request.user.skip_confirmation! && @account_request.office.save && @account_request.save
      @account_request.user.administrated_offices << @account_request.office
      sign_in(:user, @account_request.user)
      redirect_to edit_dentistry_path(@account_request.office.slug, step: 3)
    else
      if user.present?
        flash[:alert] = 'You already have account with this email please login and create clinic from admin section.'
      else
        flash[:alert] = "#{@account_request.office.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}  #{@account_request.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
      end
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end
  end

  private

  def permitted_account_request_params
    params.require(:account_request).permit!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be the reason if your user is not valid that means failing of any validation, Check you user for

`user.save` `user.valid?` and `user.errors`

Try these and you will see the issue behind this, This is not the bug in devise its the understanding issue :)